# Nearly perfect correlation observed in the real world

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I am searching for nice examples from the real world where the correlation in terms of the [Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) is nearly perfect (like 0.99 or something doesn't really matter). Maybe some examples from natural sciences?

The reason is because I want to point out that one needs a smaller sample size in order to show that a very high correlation is significant. The intuition being:

If a correlation is 0.1 you need a greater sample size to prove that its significant than if it were 0.99, [because the correlation coefficient is normally distributed](https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta215/lec/Fish1915.pdf) and it would be much more likely that a low correlation is observed by pure chance than a high one.

Comment: You almost always get a correlation of 1 or -1 if the sample size is 2. ;-)

Comment: Experimental measurement, for example of [Hooke's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law), with imperfect apparatus?

Comment: Check http://www.google.com/trends/correlate I am sure that among thousands possible random correlations you could find one that is equal to 1.

Comment: Many high correlations here:  https://churchm.ag/spurious-correlations/